# test a form redirect with cypress assert?

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
<form
    id="payment"
    method="post"
    action="http://somewhere-external.com"
    >
</form>


//after some user actions
$('#payment').submit()
```

How do I test with cypress for above scenario? it is testable if the form is submitted via ajax, but my application required a form submit.

Comment: During on submit, does the application opening a new tab while navigating to the  'somewhere-external.com' site ?

Comment: I would like to here 2 answer? my situation is not opening a new tab, but I would also like to know how would you test if opening a new tab.